# MySQL insert duplicate value (not PK)

Tags: mysql

I need to allow an application to insert data to a MySQL database. For various reasons, I can not authenticate the application's users in any way, so I thought about creating a user with write-only permissions.

The problem I'm facing are duplicate values in some of the tables, which I don't want to allow. For example, there is a table with primary key ID and SHA1 column. If the app wants to insert something to the table but the SHA1 is already there, nothing should happen (no error should be reported) but `LAST_INSERT_ID()` should return the ID of the row with this particular SHA1.

I had a look at `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY` and `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` but I'm still not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can you please post your DB schema?  Just run `DESCRIBE tablename` and post the results.  Then we can probably create a SQL statement using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for you.

Comment: If I understand well what you want, I think you will have to run the insert query with `IGNORE` `INSERT IGNORE ....` then run a `SELECT` to get the id of that key.

Comment: @CodeBird `INSERT IGNORE INTO........` will not change the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` it will simple turn the error into a warning.

Comment: @Mike `nothing should happen (no error should be reported) but LAST_INSERT_ID() should return the ID of the row with this particular SHA1.`

Comment: @CodeBird I just tried it to confirm my statement. MySQL will not return the auto_increment value if the insert statement was ignored. LAST_INSER_ID will be updated in a new record is created. and on update you can force the LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the id of the updated records by setting the LAST_INSERT_ID(primary_id); Please see my answer below of how to get the LAST_INSERT_ID() updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need to make the `sha1` column unique by adding a unique index to it.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD UNIQUE INDEX un_in (sha1);
```

Then you can do this query

```
INSERT INTO tbl (sha1)
VALUES ('sha1_unique_value')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
key_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(key_ID);
```

This query will try to first insert the 'sha1_unique_value' into the table if the key already exists. Then it sets the kay_ID column to be set to the id that was last updated returning the value you are looking for.

Comment: I just made an update to make your code a bit shorter.

Comment: One question though: even if nothing gets inserted (i.e. the value is already there), it still auto increments the ID column. Any way to prevent this? I'm asking out of curiosity because I can't see how this could be an issue, but still. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way around it. I think this is a innodb behavior. Because first it will try to insert a new record so it locks the next available primary auto increment id then it figure that it is no longer needed so it release it. Since innodb does not reuse the primary keys they it just advances the counter. I am not 100% sure on the behavior but I would think this is how it works